# Jquery: new class add problem based on rowspan length

Tags: jquery, class, html-table

How to add a new class based on rowspan length. For example, In a table some row has rowspan in td and length more than 2. I need to add a new class on those row.

For example:

```
<table class="table table-border">
        <thead>
        <th>Ship</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Branch</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Sanc</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="allrow">
            <td rowspan="3">CAB1</td>
            <td rowspan="2">HM/CAB</td>
            <td rowspan="2">SEAMAN</td>
            <td>MCPO(X)</td>
            <td>MCPO</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="allrow">
            <td>FC-I</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="allrow">
            <td>FC-I</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="allrow">
            <td rowspan="3">CAB2</td>
            <td rowspan="2">HM/CAB</td>
            <td>SEAMAN</td>
            <td>MCPO(X)</td>
            <td>MCPO</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="allrow">
            <td>FC-I</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="allrow">
            <td>FC-I</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
```

In the above table, just like first row where 3 rowspan (CAB1,HM/CAB,SEAMAN) exists in its columns here I want to add the new class `ships`.

The script I am trying:

```
$('body .allrow').find('td[rowspan]').filter(function () {
        let findTdLength = $(this).length;
        if(findTdLength > 2)
        {
            $(this).parent().addClass('ships');
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all `tr` elements and filter out using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method. For filtering get all elements with `rowspan` attribute(using [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)) within the current context(current row, use `this` to refer) and compare the length. Finally, add class to the filtered elements.

```
// get all elements
$('.allrow')
  // iterate over to filter
  .filter(function() {
    // get all elements within the element with rowspan 
    // specify context parameter to filter within
    return $('[rowspan]', this).length > 2;
  })
  // finally add class
  .addClass('ships');
```

```css
.ships {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-border">
  <thead>
    <th>Ship</th>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>Branch</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Sanc</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="allrow">
      <td rowspan="3">CAB1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">HM/CAB</td>
      <td rowspan="2">SEAMAN</td>
      <td>MCPO(X)</td>
      <td>MCPO</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allrow">
      <td>FC-I</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allrow">
      <td>FC-I</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allrow">
      <td rowspan="3">CAB2</td>
      <td rowspan="2">HM/CAB</td>
      <td>SEAMAN</td>
      <td>MCPO(X)</td>
      <td>MCPO</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allrow">
      <td>FC-I</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allrow">
      <td>FC-I</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: not rowspan value rowspan length like some tr has two rowspan (<td rowspan='some value'>some value</td><td rowspan='some value'>some value</td>) and some tr has three rowspan (<td rowspan='some value'>some value</td><td rowspan='some value'>some value</td><td rowspan='some value'>some value</td>)   @Pranav C Balan

Answer (score 1):

Try traversing each `tr`

```js
$('.allrow').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('td[rowspan]').length > 2) {
    $(this).addClass('ships');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-border">
  <thead>
    <th>Ship</th>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>Branch</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Sanc</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="allrow">
      <td rowspan="3">CAB1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">HM/CAB</td>
      <td rowspan="2">SEAMAN</td>
      <td>MCPO(X)</td>
      <td>MCPO</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allrow">
      <td>FC-I</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allrow">
      <td>FC-I</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allrow">
      <td rowspan="3">CAB2</td>
      <td rowspan="2">HM/CAB</td>
      <td>SEAMAN</td>
      <td>MCPO(X)</td>
      <td>MCPO</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allrow">
      <td>FC-I</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allrow">
      <td>FC-I</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>FC-J</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use attr to read `rowspan`

see the snippet

```js
$('body .allrow td').filter(function () { 
        let findTdLength = $(this).attr('rowspan');
  console.log(findTdLength);
        if(findTdLength > 2)
        {
            $(this).parent().addClass('ships');
        }
    });
```

```css
.ships{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-border">
        <thead>
        <th>Ship</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Branch</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Sanc</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="allrow">
            <td rowspan="3">CAB1</td>
            <td rowspan="2">HM/CAB</td>
            <td rowspan="2">SEAMAN</td>
            <td>MCPO(X)</td>
            <td>MCPO</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="allrow">
            <td>FC-I</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="allrow">
            <td>FC-I</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="allrow">
            <td rowspan="3">CAB2</td>
            <td rowspan="2">HM/CAB</td>
            <td>SEAMAN</td>
            <td>MCPO(X)</td>
            <td>MCPO</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="allrow">
            <td>FC-I</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="allrow">
            <td>FC-I</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>FC-J</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
```